# Call to a member function login() on a non-object (uFlex error)

Tags: php, class, oop, object, member-functions

```
#######################################
#### THIS ISSUE HAS BEEN RESOLVED! ####
########################################
The issue is that the object lost its scope since I have a separate function
that puts together all the template files in order and the class wasn't
insantiated within that function. I think what I'm going to try to do is
rewrite the uFlex auth class as separate functions so it doesn't lose
scope within my framework.
```

I'm integrating the uFlex authentication class into my PHP framework. I have a solid understanding of the class itself and have gotten all examples to work on their own stripped down to their bare dependencies. I have been able to get it to work within my framework but only if I reinsantiate the object just before I need to do anything with it, which is repetitive and unnecessary.

In my framework, I have an init/bootstrap file that includes all the necessary files to utilize first, in this case the class uflex.php file is included here. Then I establish the correct database credentials for the uflex object and start the uflex object. Then immediately after those files are included and the uflex object is insantiated, I include template files in a specific order based on the url requested.

For the login page example: http://mysite.com/login/

```
<?php //files included when above url is requested
include 'framework-init.php';
include 'process-login-form.php';
include 'login-page.php';
?>
```

File: framework-init.php

```
<?php
//framework code here
include 'path/to/framework-code.php';

//uFlex code here
include 'path/to/uflex.php';
$user = new uFlex(false);
$user->db['host'] = 'dbhost';
$user->db['user'] = 'dbuser';
$user->db['pass'] = 'dbpass';
$user->db['name'] = 'dbname';
$user->start();
?>
```

File: process-login-form.php

```
<?php
if ($_POST['action'] == 'login') {
    $user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['auto']);
    if ($user->signed) { header('Location: http://mysite.com/dashboard/'); }
    else {
        //handle error logging in here
    }
}
?>
```

File: login-page.php

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="login">
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" />
<br>
<label>Password:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" />
<br>
<label>Remember me?:</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="auto" />
<br>

<input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

This is the error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function login() on a non-object in /path/to/login.process.php on line 18
```

The error occurs in this line here in the file process-login-form.php

```
$user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['auto']);
```

What's going on here? The page loads fine until I submit the form, then it returns the error above.

However, this does not throw an error if my process-login-form.php file looks like this:

```
<?php
// no need to include the uflex.php file here...
// it was already included with the framework-init.php file
$user = new uFlex(false);
$user->db['host'] = 'dbhost';
$user->db['user'] = 'dbuser';
$user->db['pass'] = 'dbpass';
$user->db['name'] = 'dbname';
$user->start();
if ($_POST['action'] == 'login') {
    $user->login($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], $_POST['auto']);
    if ($user->signed) { header('Location: http://mysite.com/dashboard/'; }
    else {
        //handle error logging in here
    }
}
?>
```

Why do I have to reinsantiate the object in the process-login-form.php file it's already been insantiated in the framework-init.php file? Is this just something I don't get about OOP? Does something change that I'm not seeing when a form is submitted using the "post" method?